# WPF : How to add Checked and Unchecked events in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

WPF : How to add Checked and Unchecked events in the DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

```xml
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Choose" x:Name="choose">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
            <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnChecked"/
        </Style>
     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want both events to trigger the OnChecked Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XAML works fine the problem lies withing you getting the Check Box. You should be able to access the element from the Check Box you triggered with the Unchecked or Checked Event.

**Example:**

```cs
var ch = sender as Checkbox;
var row = data_kala.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ch) as DataGridRow;
bool ischecked = ch.IsChecked;

if (ischecked) {
    row.BackGround = Brushes.Gray;
}
else {
    row.BackGround = Brushes.White;
}
```

Comment: DataGridCheckBoxColumn  It's not working fine
if I checked on record and 
Scroll up or down
that record  I check it
It changes to another record
what am I doing for solve it.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly changes? The Text of the Check Box if yes could you add more code as Text and mark it with the {} button thanks.

Comment: {that row }
I checked it . change to another record.

Comment: Can you add the other code in your CS file to the question and mark it with the { } button please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100400/wpf-datagridcheckoxcolumn-when-i-check-on-recored-it-change-what-am-i-doing